# ASP.NET MVC Update Address Bar With Ajax Link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, actionlink, address-bar

I'm trying to create an ajax-driven gallery where each photo in a sequence is loaded with an `Ajax.Actionlink`.

The user can get to any given photo by passing a parameter to the action method, eg: `Gallery/Index?photo=100`

The problem is that when the user is cycling through photos with the `Ajax.Actionlink`'s the URL is no longer being updated (the way it would be during normal post-backs) so they can't copy paste from the address bar to get back to a photo.

---

My question is: what is the best way to solve this issue in ASP.NET MVC?  One thing I was thinking of was updating the address bar with hashtags, but frankly I don't know if this is a good approach.

I could use some best-practice advice on how to solve this problem. Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to update the address bar with each ajax update there are a couple of jquery / javascript libraries you can use as described in this blog post: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/04/08/jquery-asp-net-and-browser-history

However, the best practice solution is usually not to try and fake something like this (its only going to go wrong).  If you want to give your users the ability to share or link to a photo is to provide a field with the appropriate url or permalink to the url that they can copy from. Google maps has a good example of this - if you wanted to share a map with someone else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was considering doing permalinks Google maps style if I couldn't find another way.  The main reason I asked is because Facebook has quite a bit of ajax functionality yet their URL still updates through what (appears) to be them changing the hash tag.  I'll take a look at the Jquery tools you linked.

Comment: I think I'll just do the permalink solution.  The BBQ plugin - as you mentioned - will require a lot of effort and can easily go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into rewriting your routes to include the photo ID in the path.

E.g., /Gallery/Index/100 instead of ?photo=100. This would be why your ActionLink methods aren't working how they should, as the querystring isn't part of the route.

Comment: The Axaj.Actionlink methods are working as expected. They perform an asynchronous call to a serverside method and update an element in the DOM - this process does not update the URL (as expected).  Giving the method a route would not change this behavior. It's faster than a normal link if only part of the page is being updated, but since the address bar URL doesn't change, it's an issue here - this is what I want to get around.